# Loading Widgets properly while restoring from QSettings

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm using the below code to save my entered text. For example, if I fill a line in my gui with "blablbalbla", close the program, open it back up, that text will be there. However, using this code guts my GUI. I'm assuming it is because it's loading from QSettings and somehow my QtWidgets aren't loading in. How can I have my QT Widgets load in while keeping the code activated? :/

```
def restore(settings):
    finfo = QFileInfo(settings.fileName())

    if finfo.exists() and finfo.isFile():
        for w in qApp.allWidgets():
            mo = w.metaObject()
            if w.objectName() != "":
                for i in range(mo.propertyCount()):
                    name = mo.property(i).name()
                    val = settings.value("{}/{}".format(w.objectName(), name), w.property(name))
                    w.setProperty(name, val)

def save(settings):
    for w in qApp.allWidgets():
        mo = w.metaObject()
        if w.objectName() != "":
            for i in range(mo.propertyCount()):
                name = mo.property(i).name()
                settings.setValue("{}/{}".format(w.objectName(), name), w.property(name))

class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    settings = QSettings("gui.ini", QSettings.IniFormat)
    def __init__(self, cList):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)
        restore(self.settings)


    def closeEvent(self, event):
        save(self.settings)
        QMainWindow.closeEvent(self, event)
```

edit: interestingly, if i delete my .ini file, it works fine the first time. I'm getting this error:

```
C:file.py:847: DeprecationWarning: an integer is required (got type InputMethodHints).  Implicit conversion to integers using __int__ is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version of Python.
  val = settings.value("{}/{}".format(w.objectName(), name), w.property(name))
C:file.py:847: DeprecationWarning: an integer is required (got type Alignment).  Implicit conversion to integers using __int__ is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version of Python.
  val = settings.value("{}/{}".format(w.objectName(), name), w.property(name))
```

Edit 2:

Python 3.8.1

Here's my UI MainWindow. I haven't added any code here:

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.setEnabled(True)
        MainWindow.resize(444, 676)
        MainWindow.setToolButtonStyle(QtCore.Qt.ToolButtonIconOnly)
        MainWindow.setAnimated(True)
        MainWindow.setTabShape(QtWidgets.QTabWidget.Rounded)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
```

---

Full GUI code:

```py
from __future__ import print_function


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

from PyQt5.QtCore import QFileInfo, QSettings, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QColor, QPalette
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    qApp,
    QApplication,
    QMainWindow,
    QFormLayout,
    QLineEdit,
    QTabWidget,
    QWidget,
    QAction,
)


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(506, 455)
        MainWindow.setEnabled(True)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.layoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.layoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 480, 401))
        self.layoutWidget.setObjectName("layoutWidget")
        self.formLayout = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(self.layoutWidget)
        self.formLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.formLayout.setObjectName("formLayout")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_2)
        self.dateEdit = QtWidgets.QDateEdit(self.layoutWidget)
        self.dateEdit.setObjectName("dateEdit")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.dateEdit)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label)
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.layoutWidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed
        )
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.comboBox.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.comboBox.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.comboBox.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(312, 27))
        self.comboBox.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(312, 27))
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.comboBox)
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(2, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_3)
        self.comboBox_2 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.layoutWidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed
        )
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.comboBox_2.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.comboBox_2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.comboBox_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(312, 27))
        self.comboBox_2.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(312, 27))
        self.comboBox_2.setObjectName("comboBox_2")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(2, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.comboBox_2)
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(3, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_4)
        self.comboBox_3 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.layoutWidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed
        )
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.comboBox_3.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.comboBox_3.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.comboBox_3.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(312, 27))
        self.comboBox_3.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(312, 27))
        self.comboBox_3.setObjectName("comboBox_3")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(3, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.comboBox_3)
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(4, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_5)
        self.comboBox_4 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.layoutWidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed
        )
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.comboBox_4.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.comboBox_4.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.comboBox_4.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(312, 27))
        self.comboBox_4.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(312, 27))
        self.comboBox_4.setObjectName("comboBox_4")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(4, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.comboBox_4)
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(5, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_6)
        self.comboBox_5 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.layoutWidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed
        )
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.comboBox_5.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.comboBox_5.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.comboBox_5.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(312, 27))
        self.comboBox_5.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(312, 27))
        self.comboBox_5.setObjectName("comboBox_5")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(5, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.comboBox_5)
        self.label_11 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        self.label_11.setObjectName("label_11")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(6, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_11)
        self.plainTextEdit = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.layoutWidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed
        )
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(
            self.plainTextEdit.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth()
        )
        self.plainTextEdit.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.plainTextEdit.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(312, 30))
        self.plainTextEdit.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(312, 30))
        self.plainTextEdit.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.plainTextEdit.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.plainTextEdit.setSizeAdjustPolicy(
            QtWidgets.QAbstractScrollArea.AdjustIgnored
        )
        self.plainTextEdit.setObjectName("plainTextEdit")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(
            6, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.plainTextEdit
        )
        self.label_8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        self.label_8.setObjectName("label_8")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(7, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_8)
        self.plainTextEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.layoutWidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed
        )
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(
            self.plainTextEdit_2.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth()
        )
        self.plainTextEdit_2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.plainTextEdit_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(312, 30))
        self.plainTextEdit_2.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(312, 30))
        self.plainTextEdit_2.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.plainTextEdit_2.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.plainTextEdit_2.setSizeAdjustPolicy(
            QtWidgets.QAbstractScrollArea.AdjustIgnored
        )
        self.plainTextEdit_2.setObjectName("plainTextEdit_2")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(
            7, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.plainTextEdit_2
        )
        self.label_9 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        self.label_9.setObjectName("label_9")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(8, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_9)
        self.plainTextEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.layoutWidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed
        )
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(
            self.plainTextEdit_3.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth()
        )
        self.plainTextEdit_3.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.plainTextEdit_3.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(312, 30))
        self.plainTextEdit_3.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(312, 30))
        self.plainTextEdit_3.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.plainTextEdit_3.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.plainTextEdit_3.setSizeAdjustPolicy(
            QtWidgets.QAbstractScrollArea.AdjustIgnored
        )
        self.plainTextEdit_3.setObjectName("plainTextEdit_3")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(
            8, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.plainTextEdit_3
        )
        self.label_10 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        self.label_10.setObjectName("label_10")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(9, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_10)
        self.plainTextEdit_4 = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.layoutWidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed
        )
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(
            self.plainTextEdit_4.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth()
        )
        self.plainTextEdit_4.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.plainTextEdit_4.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(312, 30))
        self.plainTextEdit_4.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(312, 30))
        self.plainTextEdit_4.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.plainTextEdit_4.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.plainTextEdit_4.setSizeAdjustPolicy(
            QtWidgets.QAbstractScrollArea.AdjustIgnored
        )
        self.plainTextEdit_4.setObjectName("plainTextEdit_4")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(
            9, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.plainTextEdit_4
        )
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.pushButton.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(101, 24))
        self.pushButton.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(101, 24))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(10, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.pushButton)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 506, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "test"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "test"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "test"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "test"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "test"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "test"))
        self.label_11.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "test"))
        self.label_8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "test"))
        self.label_9.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "test"))
        self.label_10.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "test"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Go"))


def restore(settings):
    finfo = QFileInfo(settings.fileName())

    if finfo.exists() and finfo.isFile():
        for w in qApp.allWidgets():
            mo = w.metaObject()
            if w.objectName() != "":
                for i in range(mo.propertyCount()):
                    name = mo.property(i).name()
                    val = settings.value(
                        "{}/{}".format(w.objectName(), name), w.property(name)
                    )
                    w.setProperty(name, val)


def save(settings):
    for w in qApp.allWidgets():
        mo = w.metaObject()
        if w.objectName() != "":
            for i in range(mo.propertyCount()):
                name = mo.property(i).name()
                settings.setValue(
                    "{}/{}".format(w.objectName(), name), w.property(name)
                )


class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    settings = QSettings("gui.ini", QSettings.IniFormat)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)
        restore(self.settings)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        save(self.settings)
        QMainWindow.closeEvent(self, event)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    app.setStyle("Fusion")
    palette = QtGui.QPalette()
    palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Window, QColor(27, 35, 38))
    palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.WindowText, QColor(234, 234, 234))
    palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Base, QColor(42, 50, 53))
    palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.AlternateBase, QColor(12, 15, 16))
    palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipBase, QColor(27, 35, 38))
    palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipText, Qt.white)
    palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Text, QColor(234, 234, 234))
    palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Button, QColor(27, 35, 38))
    palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, Qt.white)
    palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.BrightText, QColor(100, 215, 222))
    palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Link, QColor(126, 71, 130))
    palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.HighlightedText, Qt.white)
    palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QPalette.Light, Qt.black)
    palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QPalette.Shadow, QColor(12, 15, 16))
    w.setPalette(palette)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>Note: The warning is caused by the unnecessary introduction of PySide2 so eliminating that import would solve it (I have removed it from the OP post in an edition to eliminate unnecessary imports).</sup>

---

The problem of why the text disappears is because in the "save" function code all the properties are saved, also save the null QPixmap that the QLabel has, so at the time of restoring the information using the "restore" function it is first established the text and then the QPixmap so the second will replace the first, so that's a limitation of the functions. Considering the above, the solution is to add more filters as I show below:

```py
def value_is_valid(val):
    if isinstance(val, QtGui.QPixmap):
        return not val.isNull()
    return True


def restore(settings):
    finfo = QtCore.QFileInfo(settings.fileName())

    if finfo.exists() and finfo.isFile():
        for w in QtWidgets.qApp.allWidgets():
            if w.objectName():
                mo = w.metaObject()
                for i in range(mo.propertyCount()):
                    prop = mo.property(i)
                    name = prop.name()
                    last_value = w.property(name)
                    key = "{}/{}".format(w.objectName(), name)
                    if not settings.contains(key):
                        continue
                    val = settings.value(key, type=type(last_value),)
                    if (
                        val != last_value
                        and value_is_valid(val)
                        and prop.isValid()
                        and prop.isWritable()
                    ):
                        w.setProperty(name, val)


def save(settings):
    for w in QtWidgets.qApp.allWidgets():
        if w.objectName():
            mo = w.metaObject()
            for i in range(mo.propertyCount()):
                prop = mo.property(i)
                name = prop.name()
                key = "{}/{}".format(w.objectName(), name)
                val = w.property(name)
                if value_is_valid(val) and prop.isValid() and prop.isWritable():
                    settings.setValue(key, w.property(name))
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. I added the code but it didn't fix the issue. I think my data is being either saved or loaded improperly. My GUI goes from having labels to the left and dropdowns with options to this: https://imgur.com/a/GIH1sq8

Comment: Sorry, it's PyQt5 5.14.1. Yes. It makes all of my labels disappear, and all of the values in my dropdowns are gone as well.

Comment: Sorry, I have to head out for a few hours. I'll try posting here again when I return and hopefully somebody will be able to help me out. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: I tried. Didn't work unfortunately. I posted my entire GUI code. I'd really appreciate it if you could take a look. You'll notice after you run it the second time, the text "test" disappears. Only way to get it back is to delete the .ini

Comment: @t0m3k Why do you use so many unnecessary "imports"? You also use PySide2 and PyQt5 since that is a source of errors, I have reduced imports with an edition to your question so I recommend you do the following: 1) remove gui.ini and 2) Copy the new code using the edited code of your question

Comment: Apologies. There was a good bit more to my program but I removed a lot of code. Another reason is because I'm still pretty new to programming and i'm terrible at it. I deleted the gui.ini and tried the new code. Same thing happened. My label text "test" disappeared.

Comment: @t0m3k I have updated your code again by removing and restructuring your code. Do as noted in the previous comment

Comment: Thank you for doing that. I just tried again and the same thing is happening.

Comment: @t0m3k Okay, now I can reproduce your problem (the text disappears) but without the warning, do you still get the error message?

Comment: No errors. The last time I saw any errors was several revisions ago. I'm using pycharm.

Comment: @t0m3k Eureka, in finding the cause of the error and I have solved it, try my update.

Comment: Brilliant! Sent a coffee your way. Thank you so much

Comment: @eyllanesc I used your suggested solution but I am having issue when restoring settings. If the gui contains multiple QDoubleSpinBox widgets, restoring duplicates the values from one of the QDoubleSpinBox into other ones. Thus restoring is not being mapped correctly. Please see this code to reproduce the issue: https://gist.github.com/Zythyr/930ed8ac09a830717a459349e942a86a

Comment: @eyllanesc. From what I understand, qApp is an instance of the application as it is originally initiated. If, however, the application creates new widgets, how to you then save (and more importantly) restore these to/from the ini file on next boot of the application? I guess you would have to update qApp somehow?